# How to put a dropdown menu in a DataTable title?

Tags: node.js, flutter, filter, datatable, dropdown

I'm new here and with Flutter, at this moment i'm developing an app to list data from my node api. I have found the way to filter that data and then show it in a flutter Datatable. Now, i want to give format to my "Cantidad" column. I though creating like a dropdown button and put it in the title of my Cantidad column. Then I will select the format between "Bandejas" or "Plantas" , these will change the value of all the cells in this columns. Do you have any idea to achieve this?

[My app screnshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkXE4.png)

I drawed it to make more sense to you, if you take a look in my cantidad title there is a red arrow, i want to design a dropdown there. It's only a simbolyc draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `label` in `DataColumn` can be any widget, you can just use a `DropdownButton` there, here's a code sample i just did.

```
return DataTable(
  border: TableBorder.all(width: 1),
  columns: [
    const DataColumn(
      label: Text('Fecha'),
    ),
    const DataColumn(
      label: Text('Especie'),
    ),
    DataColumn(
      label: DropdownButton(
        hint: const Text(
          'Cantidad',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        underline: Container(),
        items: const [
          DropdownMenuItem(
            value: 'Bandejas',
            child: Text('Bandejas'),
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem(
            value: 'Plantas',
            child: Text('Plantas'),
          ),
        ],
        onChanged: (value) {
          //Here update your column values
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
  rows: const [],
);
```

Here's how it looks:

[image: Dropdown closed]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kentukyyo, it worked for me!